# column hyperlink and pass data from master report to other report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a requirement to display data from table1 on reports. For this, i have created two reports: Mainreport and IdDataReport

Table1: Id, fName,lname,isactive.

Mainreport: It displays all columns -  ID column should have hyperlink only if isactive=true else no hyperlink.

IdDataReport: This report should display other data based on ID value that comes / selected from this "Mainreport" report.

What i have done?

I went to Mainreport report "ID" textbox->Actions -> Goto report ->fx -> iif(IsNothing(Fields!isActive.value)=True,Nothing,"IdDataReport")

After performing above I'm getting data.

Problem: 1. Mainreport - 'ID' column records are having hyperlink (showing hand icon) irrespective "inactive=false".
2. Selected "ID" column value on "Mainreport" not going to "IdDataReport" report and not displayed selected value related data.

Comment: It's working after i put expression = iif(fields!isactive.value=True,"IdDataReport",0). But under ID column, hand is showing and allowing user to browse. This shouldn't happend

Comment: is fields!isactive.value column a Text or a boolean ?